# Auto hiding div issue in css

Tags: css

I am trying to show `div` after **10s**.

It gets success, but it is also **hiding automatically**.

I don't want to hide it!

I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/omarqa/fs69z2e7/

Comment: Please, paste code here.

Comment: Your keyframes all have opacity 0 at 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `opacity: 0;` from class `element-to-animate`

New code:

```
.element-to-animate {
    -webkit-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 10s;
    -moz-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 10s;
    -o-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 10s;
    animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 10s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a animation, every animation has an interval. 
if you want that be loop the animation you have to set

```
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Replace opacity value at 100% from 0 to 1 in all your keyframes.**

And add `animation-fill-mode: forwards` property in your class `.element-to-animate`

```
    .element-to-animate {
    -webkit-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 10s forwards;
    -moz-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 10s forwards;
    -o-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 10s forwards;
    animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 10s forwards;
    opacity:0;
}
```